# Query with multiple string with like operator

Tags: sql, sql-like

I am new to SQL and I have this question on a homework assignment: "List the ids of customer representatives whose id is under 100 along with the total number of customers that each of these representatives serves in zip codes starting with 9 or 0 (combined)"

SO far I have this code:

```
SELECT cust_rep, count(cust_nbr) as "CustomerCount"
FROM customer
WHERE cust_rep < 100
GROUP BY cust_rep
ORDER BY cust_rep;
```

But I do not know how to add in the zip code restriction. Thanks for your help!

Comment: what do you mean by combined?

Comment: You have tagged the question with "sql-like" - do you intend that the solution actually uses `LIKE`?

Comment: What database are you suing?

Answer (score 1):

This will do what your query is doing in addition to makeusre sure the first chararacter of the zipcode is either a 0 or a 9

```
SELECT cust_rep, count(cust_nbr) as "CustomerCount"
FROM customer
WHERE cust_rep < 100
AND (
    // adding quotes to avoid implicit conversion
    LEFT(ZipCode, 1) = '0'
    OR LEFT(ZipCode, 1) = '9'
)

GROUP BY cust_rep
ORDER BY cust_rep;
```

Comment: While the database is likely to convert the `0` to `'0'`, it would be better to explicitly put a string there instead of hoping that the conversion will do what you want. Or it might be that it converts `LEFT(ZipCode, 1)` to a number - I can't remember which will take precedence: can you?

Comment: If the zipcode is a number already, I think it will keep it as a number so it will compare 0 = 0 , it wont do implicit conversion.  If it is a varcahr, i think it will do an implicit conversion to convert the LEFT() value of '0' to a int of 0  on the right and then match that to the 0.  Either way it would work as long as the LEFT is guaranteed to return a number it just may do implicit conversions.

Comment: `LEFT` is a string function, so it cannot keep it as a number. You should provide at least a link to documentation which gives the conversion precedence rules to explain why you have not put quotes around `0` and `9`. Or just put the quotes in. This is the second hint to avoid a downvote ;)

Comment: I updated to add single quotes and a note about implicit conversion.  I tested the version out without the quotes on one of my tables in my DB before posting to make sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT CUST_REP, COUNT(*) as "CustomerCount"
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE cust_rep < 100 
   AND (zipCode like '0%' OR zipCode like '9%')
GROUP BY cust_rep
ORDER BY cust_rep;
```

Comment: Also, without knowing the type of the zip column, this could be incorrect (yes, I saw a real DB with numeric zips-don't ask me why).

Comment: numeric zips can't started with 0 ;)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html specifically `ZEROFILL`.